# Install mysql-php5 to specific php file

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, mysql, php, zend-server

I'm running an Ubuntu OS 14.04 hosting Nginx with Zend Server and Apache listening on separate ports.  I managed to install Zend Server without any hassle.

In an attempt to run Apache beside Nginx, I've set this up manually by using `apt-get install apache2` and enabled php in it.  Basically I have two `php.ini` configuration files on the machine.

What I'm having trouble with is trying to install the mysql classes in the Apache/PHP setup.  I try running `apt-get install php5-mysql` and it ends up downloading files for the Zend Server `php.ini` config, corrupting Zend.

Does anyone know how to specify which php file to add the extensions?  As an aside, I tried linking the mysql extension available in Zend into the apache2 `php.ini` file like this:

```
    extension = /usr/lib/php5/20121212/mysql.so;
```

but this didn't work.

To summarise:  Zend Server works great with all `mysql/mysqli` classes.  PHP runs on apache2 but has no access the `mysql/mysqli` classes.  I can post details of config files if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think with apt-get you could give parameters so it would know which php.ini to use.

I think you could either try to compile the module, or download the .deb file from the repo, and extract the contents with 'ar' first followed by extracting the data tar gzip. Then you could move the file over manually.